# Denied root access to user mounted FUSE file system

Tags: permissions, mount, root, sshfs

Let me start with giving you the details of my setup:

I am running Fedora 13 on an x86_64 arch. I have mounted a remote directory using sshfs:

```
jim@localsite $ sshfs jim@remotesite:/home/jim /home/jim/remotemount
```

Now if su to root and try to read the content under the mount point, I get:

```
root@localsite $ ls -l /home/jim/remotemount
ls: cannot access remotemount: Permission denied
root@localsite $ ls -l /home/jim
total 0
drwxrwx---. 1 jim jim      90 Oct 1 12:00 bin
drwxrwx---. 1 jim jim      90 Oct 1 12:00 dev
d?????????? ? ?   ?         ?           ? remotemount
drwxrwx---. 1 jim jim      90 Oct 1 12:00 tmp
```

Seeing that root cannot access the remotemount directory is rather odd. Is this expected behavior? If so, why? If not, any lead on how to go about fixing it will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is by design in fuse as a security measure.  Pass the `-o allow_root` or `-o allow_other` option when mounting the filesystem with [sshfs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs).

It is in place to prevent from root from being nosy on shared systems.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was looking for. Also, the line "user_allow_other" needs to be added to "/etc/fuse.conf" to allow using allow_root option.

Comment: What's to prevent root from simply logging in as the target user and bypassing the limitation?

Comment: Nothing stops root from using su/sudo to become a user. Root is root, It is all powerful. So the answer is, don't give root privileges to anyone that you don't want to have access. That setting isn't really intended to stop root though. It is more about making it so various scripts/tools/services that might run as root don't get that access by default.  So it is more of a guardrail then a true limitation.

Answer (score 0):

found `ls: cannot access system: Permission denied` after sshfs on mint/ubuntu.

```
sudo adduser <username> fuse
```

remove from comment `user_allow_other` in file /etc/fuse.conf. 
Change permission of fuse.conf `sudo chmod a+r /etc/fuse.conf`
reboot now and do

```
sshfs <login>@<ip_of_machine>:<path_to_mount> <mountpoint> -o allow_other
```