# Mount SSHFS via FSTAB - Permissions Problem

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, network-attached-storage, sshfs

I am having trouble mounting a remote file system via SSHFS/Fstab.  The Client is a Ubuntu 10.10 box.  The remote device is a Netgear ReadyNAS Pro.  I created ssh keys already and can login without a password from the Ubuntu device to the NAS.

If I SSH to the device and then cd to the /c/backup directory I can read/write without problems.  When I mount with fstab, I get a successful mount, I just cant access it.  I am being told I do not have permission.  dmesg is not giving me any hints.  The line in my fstab is:

sshfs#user1@192.168.120.28:/c/backup /home/user1/NAS-28/backup fuse user 0 0

user1 is a member of the fuse group.  The permissions on /c/backup on the remote device are 777, nobody:nogroup.  I would like to keep the owner/group the same because windows clients map this drive in their login scripts and I would not want to interfere with that.  /home/user1/NAS-28/backup exists locally, and the permissions are 777, user1:user1.

Any ideas?  I can provide any information needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/188894/denied-root-access-to-user-mounted-fuse-file-system/188896#188896

Comment: have you tried to add **-o idmap=user** during **sshfs**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have mounted the dir, what permissions does /home/user1/NAS-28/backup have?

Also, have you tried cutting fstab out of the equation with the sshfs command?

sshfs 192.168.120.28:/c/backup /home/user1/NAS-28/backup

That is just to make sure it isn't a problem with the mount method.

Additionally, you could try NFS-mounting to see if the problem is only when mounting over sshfs. NFS is also quite a bit faster than SSH, so if you are on a LAN and don't require the encrypted connection you are probably better off with NFS.

Comment: It ended up working after a reboot.  For some reason, the desktop icon that was created when it was mounted, was trying to open in gedit.  No clue why, thats what was giving the error.  The actual mounting worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is over SSH tunnel, so only **user1**, or whoever the owner of the SSH key is, will have access.